# Bash regular expression

Tags: bash

I need to write a regular expression in bash to find the words with 5 characters where the last character is 'c' and the words contain a '.' (dot).
And also  to write a unix command to get a list of all the details for all active processes for all the users. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need 2 separate questions.

Comment: As glenn jackman said, please ask two different questions for two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

First Q: `[[ $word =~ ^(\....|.\...|..\..|...\.)c$ ]]`

Second Q: `ps -ef`